# How can I combine this two methods into one method?

Tags: method

```
public class AssessApex {
 @AuraEnabled
    public static List<CLIN_Form.QuestionGroup> getQuestionGroupIds(Id formId)
    {
        List<CLIN_Form.QuestionGroup> qgIdsList = new List<CLIN_Form.QuestionGroup>();
        for (QuestionGroup__c qg :
            [
                SELECT Id, Name, Theon__Title_Long__c FROM Theon__QuestionGroup__c WHERE Theon__FormLookup__c =:formId ORDER BY Order__c ASC
            ]
        )
        {
            qgIdsList.add(new CLIN_Form.QuestionGroup(qg));
        }
        return qgIdsList;
    }

     @AuraEnabled
    public static String fetchFormId(String formsubType){
        try{
            Form__c form = [Select Id from Form__c Where SubType__c =:formsubType ];
            return form.Id;
        }Catch(Exception ex){
            return null;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: why do you want to combine these two methods. Both are performing two separate logic. And going by AuraEnabled annotation, these two methods would be called from Lightning component with separate variables in different scenarios.

Comment: because I want to get the form Id in controller.JS

Comment: Is there a way to combine those above methods ?

Comment: So, basically you are calling the fetchFormId method first and then getQuestionGroupIds method by using the form id returned by fetchFormId method. If this is the case, You can combine both the method. Let me know if my assumption is right

Comment: you are right, that's exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comment,
What you have to do is change the input parameter of **getQuestionGroupIds** method as String formsubType and query the form record inside it. You can further use the form id of the form record in inline for loop query.

```
 public class AssessApex {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<CLIN_Form.QuestionGroup> getQuestionGroupIds(String formsubType)
    {
        try{
            List<CLIN_Form.QuestionGroup> qgIdsList = new List<CLIN_Form.QuestionGroup>();
            List<Form__c> formList = [Select Id from Form__c Where SubType__c =:formsubType ];
            if(formList.size()>0 && formList!=null){
                for (QuestionGroup__c qg :[SELECT Id, Name, Theon__Title_Long__c FROM Theon__QuestionGroup__c WHERE Theon__FormLookup__c =:formList[0].Id ORDER BY Order__c ASC])
                {
                    qgIdsList.add(new CLIN_Form.QuestionGroup(qg));
                }
            }
            return qgIdsList;

        }Catch(Exception ex){
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: oh I see.. Got it. Basically I have 2 picklist  fields  and 3 *form type* picklist values in first picklist field when I select the picklist value in first picklist field related question groups should display in second pickllist.

Comment: You can open another thread with your new doubts with proper details like what you have tried and where did you get stuck and what is not working?

Comment: Thank you Sanket.. really appreciated, you saved my time.

Comment: Sure, I will open another thread if needed for sure.

Comment: @https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/58939/sanket-kumar I think something is wrong with `for loop`. nothing is display and debugged too. no log is displaying.
```system.debug(new CLIN_Form.QuestionGroup(qg));
qgIdsList.add(new CLIN_Form.QuestionGroup(qg));```